# Sql LEFT JOIN from multiple id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show all category name with my multiple id on my json but only one category name appears

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.cat_id, a.name, b.category_name FROM users a LEFT JOIN category b ON n.cat_id = b.id";
$categories = $this->get_list_result($query);
$respon = array(
    'posts' => $categories
);
$this->response($this->json($respon), 200);
```

my function is

```
public function get_list_result($query) {
    $result = array();
    $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($r->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

user table:

```
id  |   cat_id  |   name
1   |   3,5     |   joe
2   |   6       |   david
3   |   4,5     |   james
4   |   7,6     |   robert
```

category table:

```
id  |   category_name
3   |   apple
4   |   banana
5   |   strawberry
6   |   kiwi
7   |   watermelon
```

output;

```
posts: [
    {
    cat_id: "3,5",
    name: "joe",
    category_name: "apple",
    },
    {
    cat_id: "6",
    name: "david",
    category_name: "kiwi",
    },
    {
    cat_id: "4,5",
    name: "james",
    category_name: "banana",
    },
    {
    cat_id: "7,6",
    name: "robert",
    category_name: "watermelon",
    }
]
```

but output should be like that;

```
posts: [
    {
    cat_id: "3,5",
    name: "joe",
    category_name: "apple, strawberry",
    },
    {
    cat_id: "6",
    name: "david",
    category_name: "kiwi",
    },
    {
    cat_id: "4,5",
    name: "james",
    category_name: "banana, strawberry",
    },
    {
    cat_id: "7,6",
    name: "robert",
    category_name: "watermelon, kiwi",
    }
]
```

How Can I do that, sorry for my bad English. Thanks for your help.
I have edited my question, waiting for your reply.

Comment: I have edited my question @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use next query:

```
select
    user.cat_id, user.name,
    group_concat(category_name)
from user
join category on  find_in_set(category.id, user.cat_id)
group by user.cat_id, user.name;
```

You can try it [here on PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=25fc8a36e50e8507be326db1473ffd08&sqlses=ebf34c2732a49c06c05dc0d235bdbe7a&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)